# PhantomJS: respect viewport meta

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, viewport

Is there a way to make PhantomJS respect the viewport meta tag? If not, is there any way to write a selenium test for a browser that respects the said tag? I'd like to do some automated testing for mobile browsers.

Details:
I find that PhantomJS does not respect viewport meta tag. I am using PhantomJS with selenium. To set PhantomJS's viewport size, I use `driver.manage.window.setSize( new Dimension( 320, 800 ) )`. My meta tag looks like: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=800">` I would assume that if a browser respects the meta tag, it would render my website at 800px, as is true for mobile browsers I tested this with. However, PhantomJS doesn't do this. So is there a way to force this?

Comment: Ok, that's a little more specific, but can be better. Do you have example screenshots how it's rendered and what you expected it to be? (Btw, I haven't experimented with the meta tags and viewports in PhantomJS so yI can't offer any guidance, but I just want to make the question better to increase the possibility that somebody else can answer it)

Comment: @ArtjomB. That's understandable and thank you for that,  although your initial comment is contradictory to this, so would you mind deleting that? 'It does respect it'